# Metabox messes up permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, metabox

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'la_season_sponsor_add_metaboxes' );
function la_season_sponsor_add_metaboxes()
{
    // TEMP-FIX FOR FAULTY PERMALINKS
    global $post, $wp_query;
    $wp_query->post = $post;

    // ADD META BOX
    add_meta_box( 'la_season_sponsor_metaboxid', 'League Sponsor', 'la_seasons_sponsor_metaboxes_container', 'league', 'side', 'default' );
}
?>

<?php
    function la_seasons_sponsor_metaboxes_container( $post )
    {
        $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
        $selected = isset( $values['la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select'][0] ) : ”;
        ?>
        <p>
            <select name="la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select" id="la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select" style="width:100%;">
                <option value="select a sponsor">Please select a sponsor</option>
                    <?php
                    $laleaguesponsor = array( 'post_type' => 'sponsors', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'asc', );
                    $laleaguesponsorloop = new WP_Query( $laleaguesponsor );
                    while ( $laleaguesponsorloop->have_posts() ) : $laleaguesponsorloop->the_post();
                    ?> <option value="<?php the_title(); ?>" <?php selected( $selected, get_the_title() ); ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></option>
                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="la_season_sponsor_nonce" id="la_season_sponsor_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'la_season_sponsor_nonce' ); ?>" />

        <?php
    }

add_action( 'save_post', 'la_seasons_sponsor_metaboxes_save' );
function la_seasons_sponsor_metaboxes_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( !isset( $_POST['la_season_sponsor_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['la_season_sponsor_nonce'], 'la_season_sponsor_nonce' ) ) return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) return;

    if( isset( $_POST['la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select', esc_attr( $_POST['la_seasons_sponsor_metabox_select'] ) );
}

?>
```

I'm struggling big time with this problem. I've made meta box which reads out sponsors, and saves it to a other cpt. Which is great.

But the metabox messes with my permalinks. It uses the last sponsor-cpt as a name. I've searched the forums, rebuild the code in different ways but I can't seem to find a proper fix for it.

I don't want to ask to many questions, because I want to learn from my own mistakes. But I'm out of options.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried running `flush_rewrite_rules()` once (and only once)? Also, it's not clear how your permalinks are broken?

Comment: I've edited the post with a example. 

And yes, I tried to use the flush_rewrite_rules(), but that didn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Your loop overwrites the global $post var, I don't think wp_reset_postdata works on admin queries.

Comment: So, with my code I'm overwriting the global $post var which causes the permalink to reflect my code instead of his normal code.

Do you have any suggestions to get the same result, which I'm after but without overwriting the standard $post?

And to all; Thanks for the help. It's really appreciated.

Comment: I found a solution for the permalink- problem. The use of new_query has trouble resetting, because it wasn't the way Wordpress was built as is, right now. But there is a (dirty) quick- fix. I will edit my post with the 'fix'.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code before add_meta_box. I have updated the first post as well.

```
// TEMP-FIX FOR FAULTY PERMALINKS
global $post, $wp_query;
$wp_query->post = $post;
```